# Do i use Unique Index with additional Column or Index with less Column?,

Tags: mysql, sql

For a Table that i'll just `SELECT` rows from it,

It has 3 Columns `[A, B, C]`.

I can create one of those two `INDEXES`

```
ALTER TABLE `table` ADD INDEX `A_B` (`A', `B`),ADD INDEX `B_C` (`B`, `C`);
```

OR

```
ALTER TABLE `table` ADD UNIQUE INDEX `A_B_C` (`A`, `B`, `C`),ADD INDEX `B_C` (`B`, `C`);
```

Both works at the same speed, and has the same result in `EXPLAIN`.

How do i decide what to chose?

**Normal** one is 4 Columns, and **Unique** one is 5 Columns to prevent Duplication,

But i'll just `SELECT` on the `table`, So is it better to use The **Normal**? Or using the **Unique** won't make any different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a slight overhead to having more columns in an index.

However, I prefer the unique index because it also ensures uniqueness -- that is, it enforces a property about the table that you want.

Note that if you have defined the trio of columns as `unique`, there is not need to have a separate index on them.

I should add that if all the conditions in your queries are equality conditions, then one unique index might suffice.